# Pros and Cons for Large Shared Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an 11 sheet excel workbook that both a coworker and I need to update at the same time. It has a large amount of formulas, some macros, and conditional formatting. We both need to enter data into different areas and if we could work at the same time, we could get much more done in a smaller time frame.

My questions are:

1. Should something with a lot of formulas and formatting be subject to a shared workbook?
2. Can I reverse the process?
3. Since we are using this just to enter numbers, could we enter the numbers and then unshare the document when we need to properly update the form?

Comment: At some point you'd be better off moving all of the data to Access, and having users submit via a form. (Or spreadsheet)  - You can still do all of the analysis and formatting you would in Excel, but you have the added scalability of being able to manage multiple users etc.

Comment: is there any easy methods to moving a very complicated excel sheet into access without compromising macros, formulas, and formatting?

Comment: It would depend on what you'd consider easy! - From experience, there does come a point where key spreadsheets like these have to bite the bullet and be upscaled to Access.  Johns suggestion is all well and good, however you are essentially trying to mimic Access functionality in Excel, and it all ends up being incredibly convoluted.  - There is no reason why the core data couldn't be put into Access tables, and you have Excel still do all of the legwork with the formulas/formatting etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a system where several "little Indians" put their stats into their own spread sheet and those stats are written to a delimited text file, so when the "Chief Indian" opens his workbook he can press a button to go import all of those text file stats.  Perhaps you can try something like that.  I've found that using the shared workbook function is a problem because someone will  eventually come along and try to change something on a sheet and mess up all the formula addresses.

I used the delimited text files because our shared server was 500 miles away and opening 18 different excel workbooks to gather data took about 30 minutes, while opening 18 small text files only took about a minute.  But if your shared server is local then you can also open the other workbooks and gather their data fairly quickly.

I disabled the "X" close button and added a button on the "little Indians" sheet that closes their workbook and writes the text file.  If a text file has already been written for that date it will ask if they want to add the new data to the old or replace the old data with this new data.  Of course they can cancel also.  It's a lot of extra coding but it prevents "little Indians" from making changes that destroys the formula addresses.

Comment: That would be perfect if I were sharing this with some staff in particular; however, we are currently only sharing this among 3 well trained staff on a local server. Would this still cause an issue?

Comment: My philosophy is Murphy's rule.  If it CAN happen, it will happen.  I try to leave the possibility of user manipulation to an absolute minimum on important workbooks, and perhaps backup the workbook frequently.  @bushel has a good point.  Even in Excel I find allowing the user to enter data through forms limits their ability to jack the formulas on the worksheets.

Comment: @John Muggins, I agree and also go to the effort of password protecting sections of the sheets so they cannot change formulae : have had the excuse "I didn't understand the formula in the cell so I deleted it" (note : the person is still alive... :)  )

Comment: I've had users say "I just didn't like the way the sheet looked.  So I put column D data into Col A because that's the particular part that is important to my job."  It's a tough world.  For critical data I like the onOpen function Sheets("SheetName").Visible = xlVeryHidden and allow users to only change data through userforms.